# Different Path Based on Directory

Tags: linux, macos, terminal, path

I am developing an application using Play! Framework version 1.2.4. So I have downloaded this and added its `bin/` folder to my path.

However, I am getting ready to start another Play! Framework project using version 2.2.0 which is a different version.

I don't want to just change my path because then I won't be able to work on my first project.

I have considered symlinking `bin/play` to each project's root but that doesn't seem like the right solution. Additionally, I would rather not have two commands (`play` and `play2`) which are aliased to their respective commands.

What is the right way to do this?

Comment: I'd like an answer to that too. My current approach is to have a script in the project directory that does `export the-bin-dir/:$PATH`, where `the-bin-dir` contains the binaries for that project. But it's easy to forget calling that script at the beginning of a programming session.

Comment: Of course, I meant to say `export PATH="the-bin-dir/:$PATH"`.

Comment: why you don't want to use different commands `play` and `play2`?

Comment: For the same reason that ruby users don't want to use ruby193, rub199 and ruby202 - you constantly have to know which version of ruby you used for that project and if you use the wrong one, it won't work. Of course, ruby users have RVM and rbenv to manage the global "ruby" command and the directory specific "ruby" command.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Write the following script:

```
#!/bin/sh
projdir1="$HOME/project/aardvark"
playdir1=/bin/play1.2.4
projdir2="$HOME/project/battlestar"
playdir2=/bin/play2.2.0
        ︙
case "$PWD" in
  "$projdir1" | "$projdir1"/*)
        export PATH="$playdir1":"$PATH"
        ;;
  "$projdir2" | "$projdir2"/*)
        export PATH="$playdir2":"$PATH"
        ;;
    ︙
  *)
        echo "I don't know which version of \"play\" to use in $PWD"
        exit 1
esac
exec $(basename "$0") "$@"
```

Put it in your `bin` directory with the name `play`,
with links to the names of any other commands that reside in the `play` directory
(if any). 
Now you can just type the command you want,
and the script will figure out which version to run. 
(Of course your private `bin` directory must occur near the beginning of your `PATH`,
before any Play! Framework directories.)

If you want to type commands like

```
play project/aardvark/foo
```

while in your home directory, this will need a little more work. 
If you want to be able to do

```
play ../battlestar/bar
```

while in `projects/aardvark`, that’ll be somewhat harder.

---

A drawback of the above is that requires that the `play` script, in your `bin` directory,
must be updated whenever you define a new project (or redefine an old one). 
Here’s an approach that allows localizing the configuration information
in the project directories:

```
#/bin/sh
case "$PWD" in
  "$HOME"/*)
        # OK
        ;;
  *)
        echo "This script should be used only within your home directory tree."
        exit 1
esac
rcfile=".playrc"
while [ ! -f "$rcfile" ]
do
    rcfile="../$rcfile"
done
. "$rcfile"
exec $(basename "$0") "$@"
```

Then put a `.playrc` file in each project root directory, saying

```
export PATH="play_dir_for_this_project":"$PATH"
```

and put a `.playrc` file in your home directory, saying

```
echo "You aren’t in a \"play\" project directory."
exit 1
```

as a backstop. 
Better error handling can be added, and is left as an exercise.

Comment: That's actually pretty clever. Unfortunately, it means you have one global file to which you need to add entries everytime you start a new project. It's not localised to the project directory. Still best solution I've seen so far!

Comment: Awesome, I hope you get the bounty!

Comment: Just realized I control myself who gets the bounty. :-)

Comment: Yeah, I was wondering what you meant.  Thanks!